# Can "trunk" mean the stem of any plant, not just trees?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

Is the word 'trunk' only used in the meaning of a stem of a tree, or can it also be used in the meaning of a stem of any plant?

Answer (score 11):

Trunk has many meanings.  Among them is the "single, more or less upright part of a tree".  It isn't used for other plant stems.

Comment: Except perhaps figuratively in the sense of "thickest, straightest part" :) But indeed, botanically it doesn't work.

Comment: Basically, a trunk has to be _woody_.

Comment: Except in some very tree-like plants.  I'd be happy to talk about the trunk of a banana tree, even if it isn't actually woody (and not actually a tree)

Comment: I disagree that a trunk has to be woody - it just has to be big enough that it doesn't bend.

Comment: So basically, what counts as a trunk (like so many other biological terms) was decided before we had a firm grasp of the actual physiology and genealogy, and is based maybe a little too much on what it looks like with the naked eye?

Comment: @Arthur Why would it be "too much"? Most people aren't botanists and have a much greater need for visually useful classification than botanically useful classification.

Comment: @SriotchilismO'Zaic That sounds to me like you would prefer to say bats are birds and whales are fish (which people did do long ago, before we learned better). Some times you really shouldn't judge books by their covers. And biology is so very full of covers. We have learned in some of these cases, and I wish we could do the rest as well.

Comment: @Arthur What's your point?  You haven't provided any compelling reason why we should prefer classifications from a technical field most people don't interact with. You say it's better to separate whales from fish and bats from birds, but why?  (It's besides the point but, fish is a paraphylitic category without whales so excluding them for "biological" reasons is rather absurd.)  Scientific definitions are certainly better for science, but very few people are involved in that and even scientists have lives outside of the lab with other considerations than phylogeny.

Comment: "Trunk" is not a precise botanical term, like "stamen" or "drupe." It does not even appear in many botanical dictionaries, like this one:
https://florabase.dpaw.wa.gov.au/help/glossary#id-t

Comment: And yet it is used in the definitions: **buttress**
supporting outgrowth from base of a tree trunk.

Answer (score 4):

Trunk in the tree sense isnt usually used for plant stems, and is usually for larger stems like a tree.

Answer (score 3):

The difference for me between a "tree trunk" and "plant stem" is that I can bend a stem but I cannot bend a trunk.

If I were to encounter a non-tree stem large enough that I could not bend it, I'd probably end up calling that a trunk as well. Cacti come to mind: I would refer to the *trunk* of a [Saguaro Cactus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saguaro), even though it is most definitely not a tree.

Comment: There isn't any sharp distinction between possible to bend and impossible to bend, though. Even fully grown trees bend _somewhat_ in the wind. For e.g. thick oaks it's hardly noticeable, but a slender pine you yourself may be able to shake a good meter or so if you can get the right leverage. Where then do you draw the line? I do think there should be a bit more of a biology-based definition.

Comment: @leftroundabout I would disagree that a "biology-based definition" requires a "line" to be drawn. There is no "line" between tree and not-tree or trunk and not-trunk. There are plants that have evolved various strategies to lift their photosynthetic area up in the air to compete with other plants for light. A functional definition is a very biology-based definition, and there is no way to draw a bright line between trunk / not-trunk.

Comment: Tall thin pines like white pines (Pinus strobus) can bend by many feet (meters) in the wind. They definitely have trunks. On the other hand, a 1-foot tall seedling of an oak, which is a tree species, does not yet have a trunk. A tree only has a "trunk" when its main stem is thick -- at least several inches -- and usually tall.